# Reset Realm Object Server on Linux

Tags: linux, realm

Can I ask that are there any scripts in Linux that similar to reset-server-realms.command on Mac that can delete all realms on server. Actually I need to reset the server and clean it before use the application officially. I try to uninstall regarding to the guides on Realm website but somehow the old data still comes up.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uninstalling the package doesn't remove any data. This is done on purpose, so that the upgrade process of RPMs and debs works properly.

We don't provide a script, but the easiest way to wipe everything is simply to run:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/realm
# CentOS
sudo yum remove realm-object-server-de
sudo yum install realm-object-server-de
# Ubuntu
sudo apt-get install --reinstall realm-object-server-de
```

Please note that this will preserve your configuration, still. The configuration is stored in `/etc/realm`.

Comment: Thanks for your response, anyway, I have found a way that I need to remove everything completely by using purge then do the installation manually and it worked as what i expected, but I appreciated your response and will do it in the next time.